# Highlight element using jQuery with scaled transparent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the following effect for any element using only jQuery/plugins:

[image]

In particular it should use a transform for the scale rather than width and height animation and be usable on any DOM element.

Is there a plugin available for jQuery which will achieve this effect? It should be quite simple: duplicate the dom object with clone(), reposition the clone over the original absolutely then animate a scale transform and opacity on the new element. However, I suspect it's not as simple as this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a play around in jsFiddle, there's a jQuery .show() scale animation but I wasn't able to get it to work correctly, and I'm sure it uses width/height animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to accomplish that animation. You can use CSS3 animations and transform properties. Check out the following example I created:

http://jsbin.com/purik/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="logos">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="logo animated"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logos {
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #CC0000 url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logo.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.logo.animated {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  animation: scale-fadeout 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scale-fadeout 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes scale-fadeout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.35);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scale-fadeout {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Any idea of the browser version compatibility? Seems to work fine in latest chrome, ie, ff.

Comment: You can look at the following tables for `animations` and `transform` compatibility:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation
http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've played around with building this in as a jQuery extension: http://jsbin.com/denocomu/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

This works if the parent element is `position: relative`, and the element itself is `position: absolute`.

Clones the element and then animates it to change the size, change the values of `left` and `top`, and the set `opacity: 0`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ej38P/1/